# List<IDictionary<string, object>> adding more List<IDictionary<string, object>> with title

Tags: c#, json, list, json.net, idictionary

Hey all I am trying to add (or merge if you want to call it that) a few `List<IDictionary<string, object>>` that I have created that look like this:

```
List<IDictionary<string, object>> eachTblColumnProperties = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>
{
   new Dictionary<string, object>
   {{ "title", "Type" },{"name", "Type" },{ "type", "text" },{ "width", "80" },{ "align", "left" },
   { "filtering", "true" },{ "visible", "true" },{ "sorting", "true" }},
   new Dictionary<string, object>
   {{ "title", "Description" },{"name", "Description" },{ "type", "text" },{ "width", "80" },{ "align", "left" },
   { "filtering", "true" },{ "visible", "true" },{ "sorting", "true" }},
   etc etc...........
};
```

I will have about 6 or so `List< IDictionary< string, object>>` that I wish to turn into JSON (using json.net).

So the JSON output of all of them would look like this:

Currently I am just returning 1 `List< IDictionary< string, object>>` called `status`:

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    new { status = eachTblColumnProperties }, 
    Formatting.Indented);
```

And like looks like:

```
{ 
  "status" [{
     "title":"Type",
     "name":"Type",
     "type":"text",
     "width":"80",
     "align":"left",
     "filtering":"true",
     "visible":"true",
     "sorting":"true"
 },{
     "title":"Description",
     "name":"Description",
     "type":"text",
     "width":"80",
     "align":"left",
     "filtering":"true",
     "visible":"true",
     "sorting":"true"
 },{
   ... etc etc...
 }]
}
```

And that works just fine but I need to be able to send all my `List< IDictionary< string, object>>` within that one return call...

So something that looks like this:

```
 {
    "status": [{
            "title": "Type",
            "name": "Type",
            "type": "text",
            "width": "80",
            "align": "left",
            "filtering": "true",
            "visible": "true",
            "sorting": "true"
        },
        {
            "title": "Description",
            "name": "Description",
            "type": "text",
            "width": "80",
            "align": "left",
            "filtering": "true",
            "visible": "true",
            "sorting": "true"
        },{
          etc..etc...
        }
    ],
    "AnotherStatus": [{
            "title": "Type",
            "name": "Type",
            "type": "text",
            "width": "80",
            "align": "left",
            "filtering": "true",
            "visible": "true",
            "sorting": "true"
        },
        {
            "title": "Description",
            "name": "Description",
            "type": "text",
            "width": "80",
            "align": "left",
            "filtering": "true",
            "visible": "true",
            "sorting": "true"
        }, {
          etc... etc...
        }
    ]
 }
```

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think you're trying to get all of your dictionaries names as keys for the data they hold.  If that's the case just have another dictionary storing the name as the key and the value is the dictionary its associated with

Comment: Sounds like a `Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>` is more what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a `Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, object>>>`

Example:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, object>>> eachTblColumnProperties = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, object>>>
{
    { "Status", new List<Dictionary<string, object>> 
                {
                    new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        { "title", "Type" },
                        {"name", "Type" },
                        { "type", "text" },
                        { "width", "80" },
                        { "align", "left" },
                        { "filtering", "true" },
                        { "visible", "true" },
                        { "sorting", "true" }
                    },
                    new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        { "title", "Description" },
                        {"name", "Description" },
                        { "type", "text" },
                        { "width", "80" },
                        { "align", "left" },
                        { "filtering", "true" },
                        { "visible", "true" },
                        { "sorting", "true" }
                    }
                }},
    { "AnotherStatus", new List<Dictionary<string, object>> 
                {
                    new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        { "title", "Type" },
                        {"name", "Type" },
                        { "type", "text" },
                        { "width", "80" },
                        { "align", "left" },
                        { "filtering", "true" },
                        { "visible", "true" },
                        { "sorting", "true" }
                    },
                    new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        { "title", "Description" },
                        {"name", "Description" },
                        { "type", "text" },
                        { "width", "80" },
                        { "align", "left" },
                        { "filtering", "true" },
                        { "visible", "true" },
                        { "sorting", "true" }
                    }
                }}
};
```

This should result in the JSON you want.

**EDIT** forgot to put `new` before the List.  Working fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1u7t2B)

Comment: This is nice as well, Maccettura. Thanks!

Comment: Hum... im getting a lot of red squiggles for that code. See OP for image.

Comment: @StealthRT fixed it and added a fiddle

Comment: Thanks maccettura. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for something like this?

```
public class MyReturnType
{
    public List<IDictionary<string, object>> Status { get; set; }
    public List<IDictionary<string, object>> SomethingElse { get; set; }
}

var myReturnType = new MyReturnType
{
    Status = statusList,
    SomethingElse = someOtherList
};

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myReturnType, Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Nice Camilo! Thanks for that. That looks like just what i need.

Comment: @StealthRT I downvoted because you used anonymous classes in your example, this answer makes a concrete class all for the purpose of serialization.  Its overkill and restricting.

Comment: @maccettura did the OP state they wanted it to be dynamic? No. Did the OP  say he didn't want a concrete type? No. This could also be done without the class, using anonymous types, but remembering the structure in different methods would suck.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto the OP clearly uses an anonymous object, its easy to infer from that they cannot or do not want to have a concrete representation.  Especially when the problem at hand is just to add a key to json.

Comment: @maccettura your answer locks the OP into putting objects relevants to each other, but that's not the case of my answer. You don't know what that JSON will be used for either